# How can I get code coverage reports when testing REST API with TestNG?

Tags: rest, integration-testing, testng, code-coverage, eclemma

I have a question that's very similar to what's discussed here:
[Integration Test of REST APIs with Code Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433046/integration-test-of-rest-apis-with-code-coverage)

I deployed a war file that exposes the REST APIs to a web server and I'm using TestNG to write test cases for the REST APIs. I'm not unit testing - I'm only end-to-end / integration testing. Currently, I'm running test cases from eclipse in my machine.

My goal is to get coverage reports on the TestNG test cases.
Since the tests are local to my machine and the REST API is deployed in another server, EclEmma doesn't provide any meaningful data when I run the tests cases in my machine.

Is there a way to point EclEmma to the web server instead of my local machine and get the code coverage report?

Would it be better/possible to include the tests in the war file and run the tests from the web server? That should allow me to get the meaningful code coverage report, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way forward in cases like this is normally to start the web server inside of your IDE and run tests with coverage measuring in there. Even better to start the web server from within the tests - then a build tool like maven can also do code coverage reporting.