# How To get run time REST API code coverage?

Tags: javascript, python, api, code-coverage

I am interested in generating a REST API coverage report. We're currently writing code for API in Python Programming language

Is there any way (preferably in Python and Javascript) that I can track a set of (existing) unit tests and ensure that all related API resources/methods have been exercised, all status codes have been generated etc.? At the moment the coverage reports will only tell us if we've exercised the code which implements the API, but not which parts of the API have been exercised during testing.

A code coverage tool should be dynamic. While running the code in background API code coverage must be calculated for particular file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get advice through this question answered

[Integration Test of REST APIs with Code Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433046/integration-test-of-rest-apis-with-code-coverage)

Comment: You should flag this question as a duplicate, rather than linking to another answer.